# How to select data from a JSON file using html

Tags: java, html, css, json

I have an issue where I dont know how to select specific data in html from a JSON file.  The html file uses a xhttp for the json and then parses the data.  Currently i can display all the information from the json on the page in a table as shown below.  Is there a way I can make a html menu or dropdown box that i can select certain days from all the data or make a couple of different filters and filter the data in a certain way ?

I am trying to just be able to select certain matchdays like image 2 but i want to be able to add options on what i want to see like filter by team or day is this possible ?
any help is appreciated thanks

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCR4w.png)

[data in json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjsKK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery function filter (http://api.jquery.com/filter/) or grep (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/).
I'll provide a working example tomorrow as I am using my smartphone now.
Take a look at this example with javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_filter.

Here is how you can do it: to have just the matches of "Matchday 1" just filter the rounds array of the results like so

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var peopleTxt = this.responseText;
    peopleObj = JSON.parse(peopleTxt); //.filter();

    peopleObj.rounds = peopleObj.rounds.filter(a=>a.name=="Matchday 1");
    html = Mustache.to_html(tp, peopleObj);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;      

  }  
};
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to have help provide some code not just screenshots.

Comment: Hi Patrick, let me know please if this helped you or if you need more help.

Comment: Hi Patrick, the proposed code works as you can see on the picture and you can test it in your own code, so why don't you accept it? If for any reason it doesn't work for you please give me a feedback: It tooks me about 30 minutes to answer.